# preg_replace multiline match but preserve new lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, text-processing

I need a one liner that trims PHP from an HTML file. The trick is that I also need it to preserve the newlines previously taken up by the PHP lines.

```
php -r "echo preg_replace('/<\\\\?.*(\\\\?>|\$)/Us','', file_get_contents(\$argv[1]));" -- "./index.php"
```

This "works" but does not preserve the new lines, for example:

```
<html><?php test(); ?>
  <head>
    <?php test();

    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

Resolves to:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

But I need it to resolve to:

```
<html>
  <head>



  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

Maybe I am using a hammer to drive a screw but what I am trying to do is remove the PHP code, run the result through htmlhint and have the reported line numbers actually match the lines in the file.

If there is a better solution, I would love to hear it. The end goal is to lint files that have a mix of PHP, Javascript and HTML with their respective linters.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to loop each line and replace if it's a PHP line or in between PHP tags.

Comment: Line breaks in an html file are ignored by browsers - so why would it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one line using the tokenizer *(Ugly thing inside)*:

```
php -r 'echo array_reduce(token_get_all(file_get_contents($argv[1])),function($c,$i){return $i[0]==321?$c.$i[1]:$c.str_repeat("\n",@count_chars($i.$i[1])[10]);});'
```

[demo](https://eval.in/889715)

Advantage of the tokenizer: even a string like `"abc <?php echo '?>'; ?> def"` is correctly parsed.

321 is the value of the constant `T_INLINE_HTML` (all that isn't between php tags).

10 is ASCII code for the newline character (LF). *(by default, `count_chars` returns an associative array with the ASCII codes as keys and the number of occurrences as values)*.

The ugly thing is `$i.$i[1]` that concatenates an array with a string or a string with something not defined. `@` avoids the warnings and notices. Whatever, this trick avoids a test and the number of newline characters is preserved. (see what returns `token_get_all` to understand the problem).

---

Or with `DOMDocument`:

```
php -r '$d=DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($argv[1],8196);foreach((new DOMXPath($d))->query("//processing-instruction()")as$p)$p->parentNode->replaceChild($d->createTextNode(preg_replace("~\S+~","",$p->nodeValue)),$p);echo$d->saveHTML();'
```

Comment: THIS. Infinitely more elegant! On one line it doesn't look nice but functionality-wise - much better!

Comment: Also use `-d short_open_tag=On` to parse short tags

`php -d short_open_tag=On -r 'echo array_reduce(token_get_all(file_get_contents($argv[1])),function($c,$i){return $i[0]==321?$c.$i[1]:$c.str_repeat(\"\\n\",@count_chars($i.$i[1])[10]);});'`

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

Regex is **definitely** not the best answer for this problem, but since you're looking for an answer in regular expression form, here you have it!

**Note**: This will break if a comment or string contains `<?`.

---

### Code

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/QvVzWH/3)

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\h*(?=<\?))(.*(?=(?:(?!<\?)[\s\S])*?(?<=\?>)))
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<html><?php test(); ?>
  <head>
    <?php test();

    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

#### Output

```
<html>
  <head>



  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\h*(?=<\?))` Match either of the following options

  - `\G(?!\A)`

    - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
    - `(?!\A)` Negative lookahead asserting what follows is not the start of the string (this basically makes `\G` only match the end of the previous match)
  - `\h*(?=<\?)` Match the following

    - `\h*` Match any number of horizontal spaces (used for cleanup of whitespaces before `<?`
    - `(?=<\?)` Positive lookahead ensuring the following matches

      - `<` Match the less than character `<` literally
      - `\?` Match the question mark character `?`literally
- `(.*(?=(?:(?!<\?)[\s\S])*?(?<=\?>)))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `.*` Match any character (except for line terminators) any number of times
  - `(?=(?:(?!<\?)[\s\S])*?(?<=\?>))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

    - `(?:(?!<\?)[\s\S])*?` Match the following any number of times, but as few as possible

      - `(?!<\?)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not matched

        - `<` Match the less than character `<` literally
        - `\?` Match the question mark character `?` literally
      - `[\s\S]` Match any character
    - `(?<=\?>)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches the following

      - `\?` Match the question mark character `?` literally
      - `>` Match the greater than character `>` literally

Comment: Sick regex! I know regex pretty well, but where do you learn this 'extreme' type of expressions? :)

Comment: I play on regex101 *a lot*. I've also been answering regex questions for a few months now, each one gives me more knowledge than the last. Also, [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) is a great help with regular expressions. He usually critiques my answers, but it helps me improve on them. If you flip through some of Wiktor's answers, you'll see a wide variety of regular expressions and for multiple languages. I usually default to PCRE regex (it supports more than most regex flavours). Also, [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) has good regexes.

Comment: @silkfire also, check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/topusers. It has regex top users. Go though and see what sort of answers these users post. It's a great resource to keep if you're going to continue using regex.

Comment: Thank you, ctwheels, really appreciate the resources you've provided links to :)

Comment: I agree regex is not the best answer but your answer is still badass. Will have to take the time to understand this. Your answer depth is impeccable. I am marking @casimir-et-hippolyte's comment as the answer because I was not specifically looking for regex and it seems much better suited for the use-case but thank you none-the-less!

Comment: @dafky2000 no problem! It might help someone else in the future with a similar problem. I would definitely say casimir's answer is better, but this does provide an alternative entirely in regex.